# Bootstrap left and right margins not working with Sass

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I have ran into an issue with Bootstrap when using it with Sass.
Basically whenever I am trying to set left or right margin it doesn't do anything, but as soon as I link Bootstrap via cdn it works properly.
Also mt and mb works in both cases. I change nothing else in the code, just comment out the cdn link.
An example that I was playing with to try to figure what's wrong:

```
<div class="d-flex align-items-center ml-5 mt-5">
    <span>
        <i class="fas fa-envelope fa-1x"></i>
    </span>
    <div class="ml-4">
        <a href="mailto:XY">Contact Us!</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Edit: I have found that the compiled css file contains the following classes:

```
.ms-1 {
  margin-left: 0.25rem !important;
}
.me-1 {
  margin-right: 0.25rem !important;
}
```

In my custom.scss file I only changed some colors, but nothing else...

Comment: `ml-5` is a class. It's defined in Bootstrap OR you can define it yourself. But if you don't load Bootrstrap and don't write the class yourself, it won't do anything. `class="ml-5"` is different than `style="margin-left: 5px;"`

Comment: I am aware that it's a class. But if I use Sass to compile Bootstrap classes instead of adding it as a link the compiled file does not include ml-X and mr-X classes somehow. Everything else I used works just fine, but these were switched to ms-X and me-X classes (which I figured out are new RTL class names in Bootstrap), but I don't know how to turn it off and go back to using ml and mr.

Comment: I see, you're probably importing Bootstrap 5 when you want to use Bootstrap 4 classes. Look at the version you're importing.

Comment: So it is changed in Bootstrap 5 globally, not just for RTL stuff? Thanks!